# script to drop logins in a SQL Server instance throwing errors

Tags: sql-server, logins

Please can anyone see what's wrong in my code? I'm getting error:
Msg 3903, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

I've checked the syntax as much as I know. It works with the print statement but not with the drop login statement. The code is to drop all the logins in an instance expect the built-in ones.

Code pasted:

```
DECLARE @Login nvarchar(256);
DECLARE csrLogin CURSOR FOR
SELECT SP.name          
FROM sys.server_principals AS SP 
LEFT JOIN sys.sql_logins AS SL ON SP.principal_id = SL.principal_id
WHERE SP.type IN ('S','G','U')
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE '##%##'
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'
        AND SP.name <> ('sa')
        AND SP.name <> 'distributor_admin';
        
        OPEN csrLogin;
FETCH NEXT FROM csrLogin INTO @Login;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    drop login [@Login]
    --print @Login
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK
    END CATCH
    FETCH NEXT FROM csrLogin INTO @Login;
END;

CLOSE csrLogin;
DEALLOCATE csrLogin;
```

Comment: Your script has multiple errors. Add the tag for the specific SQL Server version if you need help fixing your code in the most optimal way.

Comment: The error message said it all... you have a "rollback" in your catch block but there is no "begin transaction" anywhere in the code...
You also cannot do "Drop login [variable]" You will need to do dynamic SQL to achieve this (That's why you get into the catch which trigger the rollback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the rollback error is the script has no `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement.

The reason the catch block was entered is because the `DROP LOGIN` statement is trying to drop a non-existing login named "@Login". `DROP LOGIN` does not accept a variable/expression for the login name.

TRY/CATCH and ROLLBACK are unnecessary because 1) the script will continue following an error and 2) each `DROP LOGIN` is in an atomic auto-commit transaction by default. Consequently, you can fix the problems by generating a single script with all the logins to be dropped and then executing the batch of statements in one go:

```
--SQL 2017 or later:
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(N'DROP LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(SP.name), N';')          
FROM sys.server_principals AS SP 
LEFT JOIN sys.sql_logins AS SL ON SP.principal_id = SL.principal_id
WHERE SP.type IN ('S','G','U')
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE '##%##'
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'
        AND SP.name <> ('sa')
        AND SP.name <> 'distributor_admin';
PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
GO

--SQL 2016 and earlier:
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @sql = 
         STUFF((SELECT ';DROP LOGIN ' + + QUOTENAME(SP.name)
          FROM sys.server_principals AS SP 
LEFT JOIN sys.sql_logins AS SL ON SP.principal_id = SL.principal_id
WHERE SP.type IN ('S','G','U')
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE '##%##'
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'
        AND SP.name <> ('sa')
        AND SP.name <> 'distributor_admin'
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') + N';'
PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
GO
```

Comment: thank you so much. Your code works perfectly for my SQL 2016 version. Thanks too for all your helpful comments, much appreciated.

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher, thanks for your helpful comment too, much appreciated